# Do I need to register my SSL certificate in IIS and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, iis, https, database-security

I have purchased an SSL certificate and installed it using IIS on my remote system.  So I can therefore access my remote system using https://myremotesite.co.uk.  All is fine, it seems to work; users can register and login to my remote site and download my GUI to run my application which stores and retrieves data from my SQL Server database.

When a user runs my GUI to access my application it prompts them for their login-id and password and, if they are authenticated, my application pops up on their screen.  All is well, it all seems to work fine.

However, I have read that access to the SQL Server database itself can be restricted with an SSL certificate and to do this I would need "Encrypt=yes" in the connection string which my GUI uses to check authentication.

Is it necessary for me to do this?  Or is safe to just rely on the IIS HTTPS service? So my question is ... do I need to register my SSL certificate with BOTH IIS AND SQL Server or just ONE of them, and if so, which ONE?

Thanks for the answers thus far .. to explain further, the GUI connects to an IIS controlled website which has specific handlers written to perform a restricted set of database queries. So my database DOES reside on my server, but it only allows my server's (local) IIS to 'login' and insert, update and extract data.

Once the IIS website service has extracted data, it then returns the same to the GUI.  So the GUI has no DIRECT access to the database.  What I am concerned about is if - by some malicious means - the database was copied in its entirety ... could/should I use my SSL certificate to encrypt sensitive data in this event?

Comment: How are you connecting to the SQL Server? Directly? Through some web service? If they just download an application that connects directly then IIS has nothing to do with the connection.

Comment: You couldn't use the same SSL certificate for both because an SSL certificate is tied to a hostname. If you are running SQL Server on the same machine as IIS, there's no point to encrypting the data since it never leaves the machine.

Comment: Assuming you did have a separate certificate, you should ask yourself what the point is: it would encrypt traffic between two machines in your *own* network. This is useful only if you need strong guarantees about data confidentiality when there could be internal eavesdropping going on and firewalls aren't enough. Few organizations need to go that far, and those that do need to do threat modeling. Just slapping on an SSL certificate wouldn't cut it, you also want to think about encrypting your backups, for example.

Comment: The above comments assume a default setup where a SQL Server database is accessed through an IIS website of some sort, be it a GUI of its own or a web service layer. If your GUI is a *desktop* application connecting to a SQL Server instance *directly*, then that would imply you are exposing a SQL Server instance directly to the internet (as in, port 1433 is reachable externally). That's a spectacularly bad idea outside a corporate network, for many reasons, and you would *definitely* need encrypted connections in that case -- but really, you much rather want an intermediate web service layer.